# I have a weird error when I open an empty folder through my code editor

Tags: visual-studio

Here's the situation:
1: Create new, empty folder on desktop.
2: Open that folder with visual studio editor.
3: There are a bunch of unstaged files in the file tree.
I don't know how they are getting into the file tree, has anyone ever had this happen before?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of files? Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Apparently, random files from my system.